# Как получить список каналов через Telegram Database Library?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Использую TdApi реализованный по этой документации https://javadoc.tlgrm.ru/org/drinkless/td/libcore/telegram/TdApi.html.
на основе вот этого примера https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/Java_Classes_From_TL

Список чатов получить удалось, список каналов нет. Рассказываю как было.

Так я получаю чаты:

```
private suspend fun getChatIds(): LongArray {
        val getChats = TdApi.GetChats(TdApi.ChatListMain(), Long.MAX_VALUE, 0, 50)
        val chats = client.send<TdApi.Chats>(getChats)
        return chats.chatIds
    }

    suspend fun getChats(): List<TdApi.Chat> = getChatIds()
        .map { ids -> getChat(ids) }

    suspend fun getChat(chatId: Long): TdApi.Chat {
        return client.send<TdApi.Chat>(TdApi.GetChat(chatId))
    }
```

Попытался модифицировать путем добавления классов Channel, ChannelFull GetChannelFull по документации.
Так же нужно было добавить константу Constructor класса GetChannelFull в класс предок Function - сделал. В итоге получаю из списка чатов каналы, и пытаюсь получать данны о каналах через supergroupId

```
suspend fun getChannels(): List<TdApi.ChannelFull> {
        return getChats().filter {chat ->  chat.type is TdApi.ChatTypeSupergroup && (chat.type as TdApi.ChatTypeSupergroup).isChannel }
            .map { chat -> getChannel((chat.type as TdApi.ChatTypeSupergroup).supergroupId) }
    }
```

Однако получаем ошибку: Check 'request.function' failed

Подробнее:
[image: скриншот ошибки]

Нужно получить список каналов и количество участников. Возможно ли это сделать именно с этой версии Api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найденное альтернативное решение с использованием уже прописанных в указанном примере классов Chat, Supergroup и SupergroupFullInfo. Происходит фильтрация в общем списке чатов через поле ChatType. И потом по полученному из этого поля SupergroupId получаю дополнительные данные используя класс GetSupergroupFullInfo